# How to merge multiple json objects into one object using PL/SQL

Tags: json, oracle12c

I need to combine all elements of multiple jsons into same-level elements of one json. By far the most popular example on the Web seems to be this one:

https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/iayr1tfbol0nl0nerhiyxaiva

It tells how to combine this:

{"1":1,"2":2,"3":3}
{"state":"AZ","car":"P1","pet":"Dog"}

into this:

{"json1":{"1":1,"2":2,"3":3},
"json2":{"state":"AZ","car":"P1","pet":"Dog"}}

Whereas what I need, to go with the above example, is to combine this:

{"1":[1,2],"2":[3,4]}
{"state":["AZ","MA"]}

into this:

{"json1":{"1":[1,2],"2":[3,4],"state":["AZ","MA"]}}

Is there a way to do it in PL/SQL without changing arrays into string objects? In other words, this is not a good result:

{"json1":{"1":"[1,2]","2":"[3,4]","state":"["AZ","MA"]"}}

The database is Oracle 12c.

Comment: 12cR1 or 12R2 - presumably R2 if the example in that link works for you? Do you know the attribute names for both source objects, or are you trying to merge arbitrary objects?

Comment: I do know attribute names. But I already found the solution.

Comment: OK, then you can add that as an answer yourself.

Comment: Oops. Never mind. The solution I found is not acceptable -- it works when the values are strings or numbers, but not when they are arrays

Comment: The brute-force approach in my answer works with arrays too; added an example.

Comment: Your second example works, thank you!  Sorry about the cross-posting; I modified my question before I saw your latest answer

Answer (score 0):

In lieu of any further information and assuming the limited JSON functionality in 12cR2 (12cR1 is even more limited, and doesn't even have `json_object()`), you can brute-force this:

```
select json_object(
  '1' value j1.v1,
  '2' value j1.v2,
  '2' value j1.v3,
  'state' value j2.state,
  'car' value j2.car,
  'pet' value j2.pet
)
into json3
from json_table(json1, '$'
  columns v1 number path '$."1"',
    v2 number path '$."2"',
    v3 number path '$."3"'
) j1
cross apply json_table(json2, '$'
  columns state varchar2(30) path '$.state',
    car varchar2(30) path '$.car',
    pet varchar2(30) path '$.pet'
) j2;
```

which gives you

```
{"1":1,"2":2,"2":3,"state":"AZ","car":"P1","pet":"Dog"}
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f2b03fd7022492f6b54a375cc09532f1)

---

> The solution I found is not acceptable -- it works when the values are strings or numbers, but not when they are arrays

This works with arrays; if `pet` changes to a `pets` array:

```
select json_object(
  '1' value j1.v1,
  '2' value j1.v2,
  '2' value j1.v3,
  'state' value j2.state,
  'car' value j2.car,
  'pets' value j2.pets format json
)
into json3
from json_table(json1, '$'
  columns v1 number path '$."1"',
    v2 number path '$."2"',
    v3 number path '$."3"'
) j1
cross apply json_table(json2, '$'
  columns state varchar2(30) path '$.state',
    car varchar2(30) path '$.car',
    pets varchar2(100) format json path '$.pets'
) j2;
```

which is really just adding `format json` to prevent quoting of the array elements; which gives

```
{"1":1,"2":2,"2":3,"state":"AZ","car":"P1","pets":["Dog","Cat"]}
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d88c7b476cdb4ab87e9b886b0ec815e5)